# PLA bubbling in the first layer of a print

Tags: prusa-i3

I am using a Prusa i3 printer and just recently I have been having problems with the first layer. Here is a picture of what it looks like.

[image: First extruded layer on Prusa i3]

I have tried levelling the bed and it seems to be level. I was using a glue stick before but it started bubbling on that, so I switched to tape and that worked once but it is not working now. I wiped the tape with rubbing alcohol and it happened again.

What else can I do to get the first layer right?

Comment: Could you provide the following values of your print: nozzle temperature, bed temperature, nozzle diameter, first layer height

Answer (score 2):

Oh wow. You are way over cooking your PLA. It is bubbling because it is BOILING. I can tell you have it too hot because the lines are all blurred as if they are liquid and pooled together.

That said I can't give you details because you didn't post settings. I would start by turning the temps to 170 °C for hotend and 60 °C for plate. Also the gluestick it self should never bubble. It is unclear if that is an issue..

Answer (score 1):

Either you are extruding way too hot, or your filament has absorbed too much moisture and the water absorbed inside the filament boils instantly in the extruder, resulting in a gap or "bubble" in the filament, leading to bad extrusion. What temperature are you extruding at with your PLA? Hope this helped!

Comment: If it is a water issue then their print will make crackling snap noises.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I had to adjust the nozzle temperature 10 °C below the minimum temperature of 190 °C!

Comment: Hi and welcome to 3D Printing.SE! Your answer is marked as a low quality answer by the community, as it is now it is more a comment on the question. Please expand the answer, e.g. explain what is the minimum temperature? Is this the minimum value that is recommended by the manufacturer?